# How to target both windows phone 8 and 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

My app is ready and is too simple, just a panorama and some pivots, nothing specific to windows phone 8.

Before sending it I want to make sure that it will work on WP8 and also WP OS 7.1. I saw in the documentations that if we target 7.1 it will work on 8 too, but at the first I have choosed targeting windows 8 and now seems I can't change it in the App properties.

- How can I know if it will work on OS 7.1 properly? ( I have not access to emulator, just a WP8 device)
- How can I make it to work on both systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just a panorama and some pivots, nothing specific to windows phone 8.

Panorama and Pivot are specific to WP8, as the implementation of the controls were completely changed to have better performance on WP8.

So your code won't be compatible with 7.1 at all. So unless you want to write a WP7 app and let it run on WP8 with worse performance than a WP8 app, you cannot have a shared UI codebase.

For libraries, I'll recommend using [Portable Class Librarie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Claus for your answers on WP tags. your are great. So this way, can we say I have lost a big community? older OS users? I didn't find any statistics though.

Comment: Microsoft does not publish any statistics on the respective userbase size of the different OS versions.

Answer (score 1):

Your 7.1 app will work fine on Windows Phone 8 without any additional modifications.

I believe you meant that you **have access to the emulator only and not a device**, otherwise it would be really easy to check how the app behaves on Windows Phone 8 hardware.

Comment: Actually he probably meant he don't have access to a 7.1 emulator, and doesn't have a WP7 device. The WP8 Hyper-V emulator isn't exactly useful for testing WP7 compatibility.

Comment: Possibly. In case of perf - true, the emulator is not an indicator of real markers. In case of standard "does my app launch and download the feed" scenario - works just fine.

Comment: thanks Den. I mean I have developed a WP8 app by targeting OS8 at first and using panorama/pivots. I liked if I could use it on OS 7.1 but it seems I can't now.

Comment: You can use Pivot and Panorama controls in WP7. If you aren't using WP8-specific endpoints, you might back-port it fairly easy as well. To sum it up - you can't change the project type from 8.0 to 7.1, only from 7.1 o 8.0.